# SQL: пары значений из одного столбца одной таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Необходимо составить sql-запрос. Есть таблица поставок (supplies): num_prov (поставщик), num_comp(деталь), date(дата поставки), kolichestvo (количество деталей). Каждый поставщик может поставлять разное число деталей (может одну, может 4 и т.д.).
Нужно вывести таблицу вида: num_prov, num_component_1, num_component_2. То есть:Вывести все пары деталей, которые поставляет каждый поставщик. Если поставщик поставляет одну или менее деталей не выводить его, либо NULL.

Уже 4 дня голову ломаю, помогите!

P.S. Пример таблицы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Удалось получить желаемый результат следующим запросом с JOIN'ом:
SELECT DISTINCT
P.num_prov, P.num_comp, L.num_comp 
FROM supplies P
JOIN supplies L ON P.num_prov=L.num_prov AND P.num_comp[image: введите сюда описание изображения]